# Telegram-x Project setup failed with error Unresolved reference: packaging

Tags: android, build.gradle, telegram

I am working on one application to integrate Telegram features in my android application. I found following source code from github.

[Telegram-X](https://github.com/TGX-Android/Telegram-X)

I followed all the steps mentioned on the readme file. I am getting following errors.

Can someone help me what is this for and how can I resolve it.

```
packaging {
    Config.SUPPORTED_ABI.forEach { abi ->
      jniLibs.pickFirsts.let { set ->
        set.add("lib/$abi/libc++_shared.so")
        set.add("tdlib/openssl/$abi/lib/libcryptox.so")
        set.add("tdlib/openssl/$abi/lib/libsslx.so")
        set.add("tdlib/src/main/libs/$abi/libtdjni.so")
      }
    }
  }

Unresolved reference: packaging
Unresolved reference: jniLibs
```

Thanks.

I tried changing version of com.android.tools.build:gradle. And also tried to open this project with different android studio versions.